# How to find the javascript code responsible changing data in an HTML element (based on JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I am scraping a website where there are clothes with javascript rendered size tables.
Sometimes the sizes are in number format like 38, 40, 50 and sometimes in character format like S, M, L etc.

**Examples for these 2 types:**

https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0872568004.html ->
Available sizes from the khaki colored one: **XS, L**

https://www2.hm.com/hu_hu/productpage.0881349001.html -> Available sizes from the beige colored one: **40, 42, 44**

The size availability data for the first one (khaki color) comes from this json:

https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/0872568.json

In this list the first seven characters (0872568) are the base product code, the second 3 characters are the color code, and the last 3 characters are the sizes. This means we have sizes like:

002 = XS

**005 = L**

The size availability for the second coat comes from this json:

https://www2.hm.com/hmwebservices/service/product/hu/availability/0881349.json

based on the previously mentioned logic for this we have sizes like:

**005 = 40**

006 = 42

007 = 44

As you can see the same looking availability data once mean size L, then mean size 40.
I want to find the code responsible for deciding which format the user will see on the frontend based on this json data.
I went through the source code but I can not find the information I need.

What I've done is to use the recording in Chrome's Developers tool when clicking on the sizes field and looking for the product code, the json url but there is nothing there. Is there any other way I can check what function is called when I click on the size field? I guess the way it handles the json file must be hidden there.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect us to analyse the website of H&M and hand you some snippets of JavaScript from there? The data structure of your JSON samples are very clear. It would not be difficult to write some code yourself to achieve whatever you want. Start with that and come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: The question was how to find javascript code responsible for changing json data in general. I just put here an example, I need a general answer to how to start searching for this. I checked the source code looking for keywords like "size", "availability" and etc. but I had no luck finding the code snippet deciding on the format of sizes. So no, im not asking you to analyze the website of H&M, as the question was not "Can somebody find me js snippet in source code?".

Comment: and even what do you mean by it would not be difficult to write some code yourself to achieven whatever you want? :D What I can do is to create a mapping table with letter to num size mappings, which would not be 100% the same as what they publish as there is no 1-1 size mappings between the 2. I would be able to write some code if I would be familiar with their logic with the json file. But im not, that is why I asked a question for a way to reach that. Sometimes commenting nothing than being arrogant is better mate.